# Building Linux Kernel (linux-4.10.10.tar.xz) from source

Tags: linux, build, linux-kernel

Can someone explain the process of building linux-4.10.10 from source for a beginner? From my research, the answer to my question theoretically lies in the $src/Documentation/kbuild directory, however, the kbuild.txt and kconfig.txt are kinda complicated to understand assuming these are actually the files containing the instructions I need to follow.

Basically, how is someone suppose to understand how to build a kernel that theoretically contains helpful documentation consisting of hundreds of lines of text and possible configuration options.

Comment: Just type "Build linux kernel" in your favorite search engine, and you will find TONS of different tutorials. Almost any one is suitable for the first time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The README file in the root directory is definitely worth reading. You can copy an existing config from /boot or `make menuconfig` to start from scratch or modify the abovementioned existing config. Then `make && sudo make modules_install && sudo make install` and reboot. But some more in depth reading is indeed recommended.